# webMathematica - MathLink linkname missing or malformed

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, linux, webmathematica

I just installed webMathematica on *Linux Debian* + *Tomcat7* + *Mathematica 9.0*.

I'm getting this error web testing any example.

> HTTP 403 - MathLink linkname missing or malformed.

The error is also written in webMathematica.log

My `MSPConfiguration` file is :

> ```
> <MSPConfiguration>
>  <KernelPool>
>   <KernelPoolName>General</KernelPoolName>
>   <KernelExecutable>/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/Executables/MathKernel</KernelExecutable>
>   <KernelNumber>1</KernelNumber>
>   <URLPattern>/*</URLPattern>
>  </KernelPool>
> </MSPConfiguration>
> ```

The kernel is running well individually, I can evaluate expressions as I want.

EDIT: I added a user `tomcat` which can run the kernel as well. I also added the path to mathpass and set the `JLinkNativeLibraryDirectory` tag.

EDIT: If I set any non existing directory in `KernelExecutable` tag, the error is the same.

- Kernel ID : 1
- State DESTROYED
- Error Text    MathLink linkname missing or malformed.
- Error Type    MATHLINKEXCEPTION

Do you have some idea ?

Comment: You state that the kernel works fine, but have you tried logging into you machine as the tomcat user and launching the kernel?  If that works, then you could try specifying more configuration settings, like <JLinkNativeLibraryDirectory> or <KernelLaunchFlags> (for location of mathpass).

Comment: Tomcat user has permissions (`sudo -u tomcat math` works - How can I check ?) and I added both tag, restart tomcat and nothing changed. I have tried to put a bad kernelexecutable path, and the error is the same.

Comment: Try checking permissions with su tomcat rather than sudo -u.  Then try to run the MathKernel with path as shown in the KernelExecutable tag.  If that doesn't help, I'd contact Wolfram.